# Describing guaranteed profit situations which are stronger than just 'superfair wager'

Tags: probability, expected-value, teaching

**Context.**

I am tutoring a final year secondary school student in mathematics. To illustrate the principles of card-counting in a situation of sampling without replacement, I've decided to show her a toy model known as Red-Black (or Odd/Even), which received much analysis from a cohort of renowned probabilists in the optimal gambling literature in the 60s/70s.

**Model description.**

Imagine we have 52 pieces of paper, and we write the nos 1 - 52 on them, giving us a deck of 52 'cards' in natural order as $D_{\text{natural}} = \{1, \dots, 52\}.$ After shuffling the deck, we represent the unknown labels of the $j$-th card in the deck as $X_j$, giving us the sequence,
$$D = \{X_1, \dots, X_{52}\}.$$
In each round $n+1$, after $n$ cards have been seen, we are offered a wager paying even money to bet £100 that the next card dealt is odd. We denote our profit after $n$ cards have been seen as $Y_n \in \{100, -100\}$, where,
$$Y_n = 200 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} \ \text{is odd}) - 100,$$

which is resolved at the end of the round after the next card $X_{n+1}$ has been dealt.

We have that its conditional expectation after $n$ cards $X_1, \dots X_n$ are seen is,

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_n] = (100) &\cdot P(X_{n+1} \ \text{is odd} \mid X_1, \dots, X_n) \\
&+ (-100) \cdot P(X_{n+1} \ \text{is even} \mid X_1, \dots, X_n).
\end{align*}$$

I've been building towards the idea of a gambler using information on cards seen and participating when the wager is *superfair*, i.e. when $\mathbb{E}[Y_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_n] > 0$ and which yields a long term increase in capital subject to short-term fluctuations.

But prior to this, I've decided to go over cases where not only is the wager superfair, but there is the stronger condition that £100 profit is guaranteed, i.e. rounds where out of all $n$ cards seen, 26 of them are even, and all cards remaining in the deck are odd.

This occurs with non-trivial probability in later rounds as the deck is depleted, and we've used the hypergeometric distribution to compute these probabilities.

**Question.**

Using just the condition of a superfair wager $\mathbb{E}[Y_n \mid X_1, \dots X_n] > 0$ cannot distinguish between the stronger condition of there being guaranteed profit in the round, and that of there being profit in expectation.

I was thinking that I could describe this as the random variable $\mathbb{E}[Y_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_n]$ having a degenerate distribution in the case of guaranteed profit, but I was wondering if more experienced members of the community, perhaps with teaching experience, might suggest a better way.

*Do you have suggestions on a more appropriate way to describe this situation mathematically/pedagogically*?